# Create Serverless SQL pool database with terraform

Tags: terraform, azure-synapse

I want to create a serverless SQL pool database (that is associated with synapse) with terraform, I can not find a provider to do this. Is it possible?

I have tried using azurerm_mssql_server provider, but to no avail, eg:

```
data "azurerm_mssql_server" "synapseserverless" {
   name = "${var.environment}${local.application_namespace}${local.location_id}synws-ondemand.sql.azuresynapse.net"
   resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg_data.name
}

resource "azurerm_mssql_database" "reporting" {
  name           = "${var.environment}-${local.application_namespace}-${local.location_id}-sqldb-reporting"
  server_id      = data.azurerm_mssql_server.synapseserverless.id
  read_scale     = true
  sku_name       = "GP_S_Gen5_6"
  zone_redundant = true
}
```

Thank you

Comment: What have you already tried? Is there any terraform code? If you tried something, did it fail?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below terraform code to create the serverless SQL pool database (that is associated with synapse).

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features{}
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "XXXXXXXXX"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "examplestorageacc4353"
  resource_group_name      = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
  account_kind             = "BlobStorage"
  is_hns_enabled = true
}

resource "azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem" "example" {
  name               = "example"
  storage_account_id = azurerm_storage_account.example.id
}

resource "azurerm_synapse_workspace" "example" {
  name                                 = "example77354"
  resource_group_name                  = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                             = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem_id = azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem.example.id
  sql_administrator_login              = "sqladminuser"
  sql_administrator_login_password     = "H@Sh1CoR3!"
}

resource "azurerm_synapse_sql_pool" "example" {
  name                 = "examplesqlpool456"
  synapse_workspace_id = azurerm_synapse_workspace.example.id
  sku_name             = "DW100c"
  create_mode          = "Default"
}
```

***Output***

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that. I am after serverless, not dedicated. It's ok, I ended up doing it in a SQL script.

Comment: @user85567 can you share your script? did you find how to set Terraform to create a serverless poll?